# How to share assets [css,images,...] in module federation with react

Tags: webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

Basically I want to find a way to share example some css file or image using module federation in my case I want to use react.
I did some research by I don't find a solid information abou that.

Some recomendations ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I found was using **[css-module](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/)**, you can use webpack or browserify in any case your css will be transform in js and you can expose it and consume it like other object/component,...

Eg:

```
[ Home Content Component]
import styles from './exampleCss.module.scss'; // using css module

export const globalHomeStyle = styles; //exporting the new transformed js.

webpack.config.js
...
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'home',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        ...
      },
      exposes: {
        './HomeContent': './src/HomeContent.jsx',
      }
```

Consuming the style from Home microfrontend in PDP Microfrontend:

```
webpack.config.js //calling the microfrontend
...
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'home',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        home: 'home@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      exposes: {
        ...
      }
```

Using the Style in PDP Microfrontend:

```
import { globalHomeStyle } from 'home/HomeContent';

...rest implementation 

<div className='flex'>
   <div className={`font-bold text-3x1 flex-grow ${globalHomeStyle.exampleCss}`}>
```

I hope this can be useful, if you find other solutions don't be shy add them here

Comment: Thank you very much for this example, this is exactly what I need in my current project.